# Play framework JSON list binding

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new into Play, and I want to try to bind a List of String from a JSON post.

I do the following:

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

Form<Person> PERSON = new Form<>(Person.class);
Form<Person> filledForm = PERSON.bind(request().body().asJson());

Person class {

  @Constraints.Required
  @Constraints.Email
  private String email;

  @Constraints.Required
  private List<String> adresses = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I get the following message:

```
"matches":[
"This field is required"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes problems:

```
Form<Person> filledForm = PERSON.bind(request().body().asJson());
```

Replace it with:

```
Form<Person> filledForm = PERSON.bindFromRequest();
```