# Play framework 2.5 Json post request binder

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have a class with the following :

```
public class NoteForm {
    public Integer id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer userId;    

    @Constraints.Required
    public String  note;

    // cant get any of the following to work
    public Int[] tags; 
    public String[] tags;
    public List<int> tags;
}
```

And a controller action like this:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result updateNote(){
    Form<NoteForm> noteForm = NOTE_FORM.bind(request().body().asJson());

    //also have tried the following
    //Form<NoteForm> noteForm = NOTE_FORM.bindFromRequest();

    if(noteForm.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(noteForm.errorsAsJson());
    }else{
        noteService.saveNote(noteForm.get());
        return jsonResult(ok(Json.toJson("Save Succeeded")));
    }
}
```

When I post JSON from $.ajax using a json object that looks like the following:

```
    {
      "id":"1",
      "userId":"1",
      "note":"adsfadsfdsaaf",
      "tags":["5","6"]
    }
```

I can't get the form's tag property to bind, what am I doing wrong?

I am currently working around this issue by just using the following code, but I am not able to utilize the Play framework validation using the form helper:

```
NoteForm note = Json.fromJson(json, NoteForm.class);
```

Comment: Weird. Does `List<String> tags;`  also fail?

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Dont you missing getters and setters? Did you set Content-type: application/json header?

Comment: Have a look at this following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828748/play-framework-json-list-binding?rq=1

Comment: @Sivakumar I did review that question prior to posting, and if you look at my code that I posted, I have comments demonstrating that I attempted to do the same thing as the post you linked.  //Form<NoteForm> noteForm = NOTE_FORM.bindFromRequest();

Comment: @develop4fun2011 What datatype you used for tags property when using `NOTE_FORM.bindFromRequest()`? It should work for `public List<int> tags;`

Comment: Sounds like that should have returned a 400 response if the tags were the wrong type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work using:

`public List<Integer> tags;`

and having the form binding like this:

```
Form<NoteForm> noteForm = formFactory.form(NoteForm.class).bind(request().body().asJson());
```

---

Logging the `noteForm` after binding gives me this (using your input):

```
Form(of=class models.NoteForm, data={note=adsfadsfdsaaf, id=1, tags[1]=6, userId
=1, tags[0]=5}, value=Optional[models.NoteForm@5cd20029], errors={})
```